# Error "code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'" al intentar desplegar app en Heroku

Tags: javascript, nodejs, heroku, twitter

Estoy intentando **desplegar en Heroku** un bot de Twitter que he hecho con Node.js, pero no consigo hacerlo funcionar.

He configurado las keys de Twitter dentro de las Vars de Heroku. El package.json, en principio, está correcto. Por el **error** que me da, entiendo que el problema es que no consigue acceder a "bot.js".

He investigado, pero no doy con la solución. ¿Alguien me podría echar una mano?

**Error**:

```
2020-09-04T09:05:15.326219+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at 
Object.Module._extensions..js 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
2020-09-04T09:05:15.326219+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at 
Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
2020-09-04T09:05:15.326219+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at 
Function.Module._load 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
2020-09-04T09:05:15.326220+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at 
Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] 
(internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
2020-09-04T09:05:15.326221+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at 
internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
2020-09-04T09:05:15.326221+00:00 app[worker.1]:   code: 
'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2020-09-04T09:05:15.326221+00:00 app[worker.1]:   
requireStack: [ '/app/bot.js' ]
2020-09-04T09:05:15.326222+00:00 app[worker.1]: }
2020-09-04T09:05:15.389873+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process 
exited with status 1
2020-09-04T09:05:15.422459+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State 
changed from up to crashed
```

**Package.json**:

```
{
"name": "addicteddev",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "Addicted Dev - Twitter Bot",
"main": "bot.js",
"dependencies": {
"twit": "^2.2.11",
"twitter": "^1.7.1"
},
"devDependencies": {},
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"repository": {
"type": "git",
"url":
"git+https://github.com/pablohs1986/
 addictedDEV_TwitterBot.git"
 },
"keywords": [
"bot",
"twitter",
"javascript",
"nodejs",
"dev"
],
"author": "Pablo Herrero",
"license": "MIT",
"bugs": {
"url": 
"https://github.com/pablohs1986/
 addictedDEV_TwitterBot/issues"
},
"homepage": 
"https://github.com/pablohs1986/
 addictedDEV_TwitterBot#readme"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perdonad, he dado con ello, así que **intentaré responder a la pregunta**:

Finalmente era **un problema de ruteo**. Al desplegar el bot en Heroku, el programa no estaba consiguiendo acceder al archivo config.js ni a bot.js.

Config.js no lo quería hacer público por tener las keys de Twitter en él. Finalmente lo he hecho público, pero haciendo referencia en él al archivo Config.env que es desde donde realmente se leen las keys de Twitter (almacenadas en las Vars de Heroku) al cual accedo mediante el  módulo [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) como muestro a continuación:

**Config.js**:

```
const path = require('path')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
require('dotenv').config();
// Load config
dotenv.config({ path: './config/config.env' })

module.exports = {
    consumer_key : process.env.API_KEY,
    consumer_secret : process.env.API_SECRET_KEY,
    access_token : process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN,
    access_token_secret : process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET
};
```

Una vez hecho el push, funciona perfectamente.

Espero que esto sea útil si a alguien le pasa algo parecido en el futuro :)